# How do I refer to multiple join tables with the same underlying model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model that looks like the following:

```
class A
  has_many :B, -> { ... where clause 1 }, source: :tags
  has_many :C, -> { ... where clause 2 }, source: :tags
end
```

so basically `A` joins to `tags` in two different ways.

I'd like to run a query that inner joins some other table with both `B` and `C` through `A` and filters based on each's attributes. Normally I'd do this like:

```
Other.joins(A: [:B, :C]).where('tags.id = 1')
```

but `tags` is ambiguous here. Is there a better way to do this?

I realize this isn't the cleanest data model, but let's just pretend I've inherited this codebase from someone else :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Other.joins('inner join a on a.id = other.a_id 
             inner join (Select ...) as b
             inner join (Select ...) as c

             where 
                b...
             or
                c...
           ')
```